# Set namespace prefix on FaultCode c#.net

Tags: c#, biztalk

I am expecting following response for faultCode to be send to client if any fault occurs in FaultException. From custom certificate validator put on BizTalk receive location

```
<faultcode xmlns:ssek="http://myschemas.testns.org/testns/2006-05-10/">ssek:InvalidCertificate</faultcode>
```

But when i have written following code.

```
FaultCode code = new FaultCode("InvalidCertificate", "http://myschemas.testns.org/testns/2006-05-10/");

throw new FaultException("Received Invalid Client Certificate", code);
```

FaultCode coming as

```
<faultcode xmlns:a="http://myschemas.testns.org/testns/2006-05-10/">a:InvalidCertificate</faultcode>
```

I want to modify prefix "a" with "ssek".

Please can somebody help me with this.

Regards
Kundan

Answer (score 0):

Related to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649234.aspx) article, this the default behavior when the FaultCode is serialized.

to override this generation, you can create a custom MessageFormatter. [there](http://vanacosmin.ro/Articles/Read/WCFEnvelopeNamespacePrefix) is a good article explaining how to do it with an attribute on contract operations.

hope that helpe you.